# DataTables search box causes 'Invalid JSON response'

Tags: javascript, php, json, oracle, datatables

I am using DataTables on a website that I'm building.

**Initialing the DataTable using:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "server_processing.php"
            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

The DataTable is shown and clicking on column headers to sort ordering etc. as well as pagination is working great however on putting something in the search box it results in the browser showing 'Invalid JSON response' and clearing the search box makes it ok again.

**Here are the error messages shown in Network tab in Developer Tools:**

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: bSearchable_3 in
>   **/var/www/portal/server_processing.php** on line **138**
>   
>  **Warning**:  oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal
>   variable name/number in **/var/www/portal/server_processing.php**
>   on line **242**
>  
>  **Warning**:  oci_bind_by_name():
>   ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in
>   **/var/www/portal/server_processing.php** on line **243**
>   
>  **Warning**:  oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal
>   variable name/number in **/var/www/portal/server_processing.php**
>   on line **242**
>  
>  **Warning**:  oci_bind_by_name():
>   ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in
>   **/var/www/portal/server_processing.php** on line **243**
>   
>  **Warning**:  oci_bind_by_name(): ORA-01036: illegal
>   variable name/number in **/var/www/portal/server_processing.php**
>   on line **242**
>  
>  **Warning**:  oci_bind_by_name():
>   ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in
>   **/var/www/portal/server_processing.php** on line **243**

**I checked the server_processing.php and do not see any errors that would cause this. Here are the related lines:**

```
if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    //Set a default where clause in order for the where clause not to fail
    //in cases where there are no searchable cols at all.
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns)+1 ; $i++ )
    {
        //If current col has a search param
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            //Add the search to the where clause
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch']."%' OR ";
            $nWhereGenearalCount += 1;
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
$sWhereSpecificArray = array();
$sWhereSpecificArrayCount = 0;
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        //If there was no where clause
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }

            //Add the clause of the specific col to the where clause
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%' || :whereSpecificParam".$sWhereSpecificArrayCount." || '%' ";

            //Inc sWhereSpecificArrayCount. It is needed for the bind var.
            //We could just do count($sWhereSpecificArray) - but that would be less efficient.
            $sWhereSpecificArrayCount++;

            //Add current search param to the array for later use (binding).
            $sWhereSpecificArray[] =  $_GET['sSearch_'.$i];

        }
    }

    //If there is still no where clause - set a general - always true where clause
    if ( $sWhere == "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE 1=1";
    }
```

Can someone see why putting something in the search box results in these problems as I do not see a problem in the code?

Comment: Can you output a string with the complete SQL at the end so we can see what it looks like?  I bet that's where the problem is.

Comment: @markpsmith I don't think the problem is with SQL as the output passed to DataTables is correct. The output is: `{"sEcho":2,"iTotalRecords":"281839","iTotalDisplayRecords":"1","aaData":[["1009452"]]}` which looks correct to me.